# When should InvalidArgumentException vs BadMethodCallException be thrown?

Tags: php, exception

In the following example, what would be the appropriate type of exception? When should `InvalidArgumentException` be thrown vs. `BadMethodCallException`? It seems like the example falls under either definition provided by the PHP manual:

> [BadMethodCallException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.badmethodcallexception.php): Exception thrown if a callback refers to an undefined method or if some arguments are missing.
>
> [InvalidArgumentException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php): Exception thrown if an argument is not of the expected type.

```
class Foo
{
    public function Bar($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        if (!$arg1 && !$arg2)
        {
            // InvalidArgumentException or BadMethodCallException?
            throw new Exception('Both arguments are required.');
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}

$Foo = new Foo();
$Foo->Bar(null, null); // Exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BadMethodCallException` should be thrown.
You would throw `InvalidArgumentException`, when the passed argument does not have the type you expect (e.g. you expect an array but you get a string instead).